# Run multiple pptx slideshows one by one using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powerpoint

I am trying to play multiple pptx slideshows using a PowerShell script after 
reading pptx file names from a text file.

File content:

```
file1.pptx  
file2.pptx
```

Script:

```
$ppt_list = Get-Content ".\filename.txt"

foreach ($ppt in $ppt_list)
{
POWERPNT.EXE /s $ppt 
}
```

It is just running first slideshow. I need to press key to stop the slide.

Is it possible to continuously run all the pptx slideshow one after another 
without any manual intervention?